# Thread restart after computer standby

Tags: java

I have an application running in the Windows system tray and it seem like after I put the computer in stand-by (not shutdown!) when I turn the system back on, a Thread I have running in the application does not continue running. How would I either A) keep the Thread running, or B) determine the system has come back from stand-by and restart the Thread?

Comment: I have no trouble for Java to resume, however, there might be some issues with redrawing graphics. The program is running, but do not handle graphics properly, is that your problem?

Comment: If you wrote the program yourself you should be able to either find out if the thread ended at stand-by or what it does now instead of providing a response.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to resume threads after the system resumes. That happens automatically. If your thread or process doesn't resume operation properly it is probably mis-handling the standby or hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the application is not 100% thread-safe and/or the thread died by an uncaught exception while the system is going stand-by or back from it. Set up an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for your thread which logs the uncaught exceptions to a file.

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) are also useful for hints.